# Inbound email with attached file

Tags: email-attachments, email, inbound

I'm creating a new web app and I need to process files (word, pdf) sent via email message (attached files).

That also would be necessary to have a specific email address to route file to a proper destination (its a job application service, so each job opening would have its own email address).

I'm completely lost and have no idea from where I would begin.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options here. You can:

- Create a system to poll an existing IMAP account every x minutes. Then download the message, parse it and extract the attachment.
- Install your own email server, and set the server up to run a script as the emails arrive.
- Use a third party service that receives the email and forwards the messages as an HTTP POST (such as [CloudMailin](http://www.cloudmailin.com)).

I wrote a [blog post](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/09/07/incoming-email-in-rails-3-choosing-the-right-approach/) explaining a few of the options a few years back now for Rails but pretty much all of it is still relevant and relevant to other languages.